# Google app engine acting as a middleware

Tags: google-app-engine

sorry if this question sounds useless . I am researching about google app engine . The point which i want to know that does Google app engine acts as a Middle ware for accessing clouds ? if there is any digram which represent it as a middle ware then please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google AppEngine is "the clouds".

Seriously, GAE is one of the cloud computing solutions and as such is self-sufficient, i.e. it does not need other cloud services to be operable nor was it designed to be middleware for other cloud services.

OTOH, it has facilities to talk to other clouds and *could* be used as middleware solution (client-GAE-other cloud), but it's not a good fit for that: for example, it does not support TCP sockets, so protocols that require them could not be implemented.